# Using the official DocuSign C# SDK, how would I go about replacing a document within an envelope that is still "in process" (hasn't been completed)?

Tags: docusignapi

Using the EnvelopesApi client, I'm honestly not all that sure where to begin. Do I have to call DeleteDocument() with the DocumentId that I want to replace, and then call UpdateDocuments(), passing in only an envelope definition that only includes the document that I'm replacing it with; or do I have to recreate the envelope definition entirely? Or should I instead just call Update(), passing in the new envelope definition with the correct documents? What is the correct/recommended approach for replacing a document within an envelope that is not completed? Is this documented anywhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First thing first.
If your envelope was "sent" which means it is no longer in "draft" (created) state, you cannot change it without using the [Correct feature.](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-correct-documents)

Correcting an envelope after it was sent is a specific action meant to allow the original sender to make modifications as allowed by law.

In terms of replacing a document in an envelope, you can use this method:

```
PUT
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

Assuming you know the accountId, envelopeId, and documentId

See more [information about this endpoint in Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/)

Comment: I don’t need anyone to physically correct the envelope - I prefer to do that using the API. Does the PUT method you provided give me that option? If not, can envelopes be corrected through the API? The envelope is in “sent” status.

Comment: The API call I mentioned here can be used to update an envelope that's in "sent" status. I am not 100% sure, but it's possible you must first lock the envelope so that it cannot be modified during this update. I can provide information about how to lock/unlock envelopes if you need.

Comment: Which C# SDK method does that equate to? In the documentation, it says updateDocument, but I don't see how or where I'm supposed to supply a new document. It only accepts three parameters - accountId, envelopeId and documentId, all of which are strings. Looking at the code in github, the body appears to be null when calling the API.

Comment: This may be an issue, I'm checking, sorry about that

Comment: @aardvark this is a bug in the SDK. As a workaround, you can use the EnvelopesApi.Update() method it takes the Envelope object just like the Create() method but you can just provide the documents to update inside this object.

Comment: Thank you, Inbar. I will try this and let you know if I have any issues.

Comment: Hi Inbar - the Update() method appears to take a different type of object - an Envelope object, whereas the Create() method consumes an EnvelopeDefinition object. The Envelope object contains a List<EnvelopeDocument>, which I imagine is the property I'm supposed to populate, but an EnvelopeDocument does not seem to contain any properties where I can provide the actual document's Base64 data. Would you be able to provide me with an example call to update a document within an existing, unsigned, uncompleted envelope using the C# SDK? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was actually not able to do this and it appears that maybe there's a bug in the C# SDK. Unfortunately, we're off for the holidays so it will take me some time to confirm this and find the experts that can help me get you a more definitive answer.

Comment: @aardvark How did you end up accomplishing your task? I am having the same issue. Did you just end up using the REST API method here and adding the bytes of the document to the body of the request?
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/

Comment: kay - We have not accomplished this yet. I don't want to use the API method directly (or drop the SDK altogether) because we may go with another eSignature provider and I don't want to put in any work that would just end up being tossed. I do hold out hope that @InbarGazit will come through. ;)

Comment: @aardvark, can you please email me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com ? thanks!

Comment: @InbarGazit Is there any update on this. I see the latest version of the DocuSign.eSign Nuget package has another parameter for passing in the byte array but it still throws an error. "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. A filename was not found in the Content-Disposition header"

Comment: @InbarGazit or anybody else that runs into this.  Starting with the code from the "UpdateDocumentWithHttpInfo" method in the GitHub repo I added the following line of code to resolve that error:

localVarHeaderParams["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"TestReplace.pdf\"";

Link to the repo page: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docusign/docusign-esign-csharp-client/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Api/EnvelopesApi.cs